# Why does eth0 only go up sometimes on boot?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, ethernet

I just installed Arch with Archboot. On boot, there's about 50% change of eth0 to go up. If it doesn't I'll have to reboot. What could cause this?

If it goes up, dmesg contains:

```
[ 7.9...] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[11.5...] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[11.5...] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

If it doesn't, only the "link is not ready" line is there. The server is configured for a static IP at 192.168.1.16, gateway 192.168.1.1 and DNS 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Try `ifconfig eth0 up` then `dhcpcd eth0` to see what happens after it has failed at boot and add that to your post.  `service NetworkManager stop` before you do that.

Comment: If OP uses a static address, there presumably is no DHCP server around (and if there is, calling on it probably screws up the configuration). Or the "static address" is really a fixed address handed out by DHCP...  "Link not there" means that the eth0 isn't seeing a live link. Maybe something in your network is broken, perhaps a cable or a connector not firmly seated, connectors dirty, the card itself, of the switch on the other end.

Comment: Two of the lines from the log are relevant for IPv6 only. Do you have lines for IPv4 too? I wonder why the nic takes so long until the link is ready. Is there an extra firmare loaded into the nic?

Comment: Maybe also check cable and the switch/hub. Sometimes this is hardware problem.

Comment: If it's a recent installation, chances are that it's using the new [predictable network interfaces](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames) introduced on systemd 197. In any case, if [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_Guide#Configure_the_network) doesn't help fix the issue, a little explanation of how is your network configured can give people clues of what is wrong.